# docker compose configuration not able to connect to mongodb container

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

In my project I am trying to connect both to `mysql` and `mongodb`. I think I am able to connect to `mysql` container. But I am getting error on trying to connect to mongodb container.

application.properties file

```
# SERVER
server.port = 5555
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/shopdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl


application.security.jwt.secret-key=404E635266556A586E3272357538782F413F4428472B4B6250645367566B5970
application.security.jwt.expiration=7200000
application.security.jwt.refresh-token.expiration=604800000


spring.data.mongodb.host=mongocontainer
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=ShopDb
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/myproject.jar
EXPOSE 5555
CMD ["java","-jar","myproject.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "5"
services:
  mysqldb:
   image: mysql:latest
   ports:
    - "3307:3306"
   networks:
    - netshop
   environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: shopdb
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
   volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: /C/Users/tim/Documents/mysqldata
      target: /var/lib/mysql
  mongocontainer:
   image: mongo:latest
   container_name: mongocontainer
   restart: always
   ports:
    - 27017:27017  
  myproject:
   image:
    timqwert09/myproject:latest
   ports:
    - "5555:5555"
   networks:
    - netshop
   depends_on:
    - mysqldb
   links:
    - mongocontainer
networks:
 netshop:
  driver: bridge
```

I first build my image. It is successfully build. Then under resources directory I run `docker-compose up`

I runs smoothly, but in end it is giving below error :

```
resources-myproject-1  | com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongocontainer: Try again
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:217) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:78) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:68) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:183) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:198) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:158) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongocontainer: Try again
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:932) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1517) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:851) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1507) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1366) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1300) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:209) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    ... 6 common frames omitted
resources-myproject-1  |
resources-myproject-1  | 2023-10-01T07:05:22.194Z  INFO 1 --- [container:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongocontainer:27017
resources-myproject-1  |
resources-myproject-1  | com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongocontainer
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:217) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:78) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:68) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:183) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:198) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:158) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongocontainer
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:800) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:886) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1507) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1366) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1300) ~[na:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:209) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
resources-myproject-1  |    ... 6 common frames omitted
resources-myproject-1  |
```

I would also like to tell that in host machine i.e windows here, I have mongodb installed but it is not running. Does it make any difference..? How do I connect my app to mongodb container? I am new to docker environment. I have followed as per tutorials and code available on internet.

Comment: I have also tried changing the host side port. But same error comes.

Comment: I am also able to use `mongodb` using `docker exec -it mongocontainer mongosh`

Comment: Yes it is able to connect to mysql - `/usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.1.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.` BUT NOT TO MONGODB container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application container `myproject` and the MySQL database `mysqldb` both declare `networks: [netshop]`, but the MongoDB database `mongocontainer` doesn't.  Since the two containers aren't on the same network, they can't talk to each other.

The easiest solution to this is to delete *all* of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file.  Compose provides a network named `default` for you and attaches containers to it; for most projects you don't need any manual network setup at all.

I'd also delete the obsolete `links:` option, which is unnecessary with Docker networks.  Conversely it will help to add `mongocontainer` into the `depends_on:` list, though this won't guarantee that the databases are both fully started before the application wants to connect to them.

Comment: I just feel my evolution has happened. Neanderthalensis to Homo Sapiens. Thank You So So Much! Feeling updated because of you.

Comment: Yes, using your suggestions, It finally did connected to both databases successfully!